# Disabling/enabling requiredFieldValidators with javascript and server side

Tags: asp.net, ajax, validation

I have a drop down (dropdown2) that is required **IF** there is something in it but it's options data is driven by ajax from another dropdown (dropdown1) selection.  Sometimes dropdown2 will be empty and in that case I can't require it.  So I can disable the `requiredFieldValidators` in javascript by calling this...

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById(validatorId), false);
```

This works fine but the server still fires the `requiredFieldValidator` logic.  Is anyone aware of how I can force the server to not validate if the validator is set to false client side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you just use a client side validator?  You are making your job much more difficult doing  this.  If you have access to it via the clientside, why are you bothering hitting it at the serverside?

The only other thing I can think of is to create a hidden field and set it via the client side, and then when you do a postback to check this value and disable / enable the validator.

For example after this:

JS:

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById(validatorId), false);
var hidden = document.getElementById(hiddenID);
hidden = "1";
```

Then in your load event:

```
If (hidden = "1") then
 validator.enabled=false
end if
```

Take a look at this post, very similiar to yours: [ASP.NET - how to stop unrequired server validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417078/asp-net-how-to-stop-unrequired-server-validation)

Comment: You're right.  I should have gone to the bathroom... the easy solutions never come sitting at my desk but always seem to hit me then:)  Thanks!

Comment: @geoff swartz - It's quite normal to get ideas after getting away from your desk..I've found myself finding solutions in the middle of the night and the strange thing is I actually want to come into work the next morning...

Answer (score 11):

DISABLE

```
document.getElementById("<%=ReqVal.ClientID%>").style.visibility = "hidden"; 

document.getElementById("<%=ReqVal.ClientID%>").enabled = false;
```

ENABLE

```
document.getElementById("<%=ReqVal.ClientID%>").style.visibility = "visible"; 

document.getElementById("<%=ReqVal.ClientID%>").enabled = true;
```

Comment: If it is ASP Validator you can keep its display="dynamic" so  you can avoid styling here to hide the validation message

Answer (score 6):

Require Validators are injected in the DOM as span elements.

If you are using JQUERY, get the element using a jQuery Selector, then get the DOM element from that selection an you are set.

Here is an example:

Lets say you have a require validator id="MyReqValidator".

In your javascript file you will do:

```
//The jQuery Element:
jqValidator = $("span[id$=MyReqValidator]");

//No the DOM element. This is what document.getElementById would return.
domValidator = jqValidator.get(0)

//Now enable your validator:
 ValidatorEnable(validator, true);
```

All in one line of code

```
ValidatorEnable( $("span[id$=MyReqValidator]").get(0), true);
```

Comment: This answer deserves more recognition.

Answer (score 2):

So I didn't get JonH answer to work, and the rest is only client side. So this is my solution:

To disable a RequiredFieldValidator on the client side:

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("rfv"), false);
```

To disable a RequiredFieldValidator on the server side you can [override the Validate() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx) like this:

```
public override void Validate()
{
    bool disableRfv = input_to_check <> 1;
    rfv.Enabled = disableRfv;
    base.Validate();
}
```

Or, in VBasic:

```
Public Overrides Sub Validate()
    Dim disable_rfv As Boolean = input_to_check <> 1
    rfv.Enabled = disable_rfv

    MyBase.Validate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoting this answer as it covers both client-side and server-side validation.

For those who can't VBasic, a C# example for this could be clearer:
```
public override void Validate()  
{   
        bool disableRFV = input_to_check <> 1;  
        rfvAddress1.Enabled = disableRFV;   
  
        base.Validate();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it would indeed be nicer to answer a C# question in C#

Comment: I've edited the answer with C# as the higher priority code example. Shift it lower if you like if you'd prefer VB as the first -- I'm not preferential, just prioritizing by higher use-frequency.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ValidatorEnable($("[id$='RegularExpressionValidator4']")[0], true);
```