# Only Validate A Field When It's Displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an `asp.net webform` and I have a hidden field which is displayed when a user selects a radio button. The issue I have is that I need this field to be a mandatory field **BUT** only when it's displayed other wise I don't want it to validate.

What's the best way of doing this and also how do I do this.

**HTML for my hidden field**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label ID="Step03PgSelectionLabel" class="col-sm-4 control-label" runat="server" Text="How many pages would you like us to look at *" style="padding-top: 0px"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <asp:Label runat="server" class="radio-inline" style="padding-top: 0px">
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="Step03AllPgsRadioButton" value="All" GroupName="Step03PgSelection" onclick="$('#hiddenSpecificPages').hide();" />All
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" class="radio-inline" style="padding-top: 0px">
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="Step03SelectionPgsRadioButton" name="selection" value="Selection" GroupName="Step03PgSelection" onclick="$('#hiddenSpecificPages').show();" />Selection
        </asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomStep03PgSelection" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please select if you would like us to look at all you pages or specific pages." ClientValidationFunction="Step03PgSelection_ClientValidate" OnServerValidate="Step03PgSelection_ServerValidate" />
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group" id="hiddenOtherField">
        <asp:Label ID="Step03OtherFieldLabel" class="col-sm-4 control-label" runat="server" Text="Please specify *" AssociatedControlID="Step03OtherField"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="Step03OtherField" runat="server" class="form-control" style="max-width: 100%"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="reqStep03OtherField" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="Step03OtherField" ErrorMessage="Please specify your website's type." />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What about the jQuery `:visible` selector?http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_visible.asp

Comment: @DFayet As I have said in my post,  the field is displaying fine when they select a radio button and also hides when they select the other. The issue is my validation only so I hope your not the -1. If you are can you remove it as you haven't read my post correctly

Comment: It was assuming you were validating your fields with jQuery. as I don't know if you are using jQuery for a validation or straight running a submission. Are you using a validation before submitting?

Comment: @DFayet Yes. Normally an `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` will trigger as soon as you leave the field blank.  This is how my validation is running.  I need a way of using this validator only when the drop down list displays "Other" as this is what triggers my additional field to be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a great way to do this would be to use a custom validator on your hidden field.

This validator would check if your radio value is the one who display the hidden field.

Obviously if that's the case you validate the field else you ignore it.

---

I found an other thread talking of an other way to do the job, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876874/disabling-enabling-requiredfieldvalidators-with-javascript-and-server-side), maybe it can give you parts of a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to check if the field is visibile.

```
$(element).is(":visible");
```

Comment: I had the field displaying/hiding fine, the issue I had was with validating the field.  I have updated my post as I have now found a better way of show/hide without using `JQuery` so now I'm doing it via my `HTML`. Just need to validate the field once displayed

Comment: $(element).is(":visible");  just tell you if the field is visibile. I do not code in ASP so I cannot help you on that.